# Where to put the word 'still' in the following sentence?

Tags: word-order

> "On the item page, [*still*] there are [*still*] two different types of
>   models".

Where should I put the word '**still**' in this sentence? Intuitively I'll go for the first choice but I'm still not sure about it.

Comment: Intuitively I'll go for the first choice but I'm **still** not sure about it.

Comment: It could also go at the very beginning of the sentence with a slightly different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

"On the item page, still there are two different types of models" is valid, but archaic, so many people would say it was bad grammar.

"On the item page, there are still two different types of models" is more normal in a modern context.